# can I split the value in a pandas row for searching?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm searching a DF using:

```
df.loc[df['Ticker'] == 'ibm'
```

The problem is `df['Ticker']` is formated with another value after it(for example 'ibm US').

normally for string I can do something like `.split[" "][0]` to find the match but it doesn't work for my pandas search above(`df.loc[df['Ticker'].split[" "][0] == 'ibm'` - fails with `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'`).

What can I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Comment: You can create a custom function by `data[data["Ticker"].apply(lambda x : "ibm" in x)]` or you can use `data[data["Ticker"].str.contains("ibm")]`

Comment: @Mr.Hobo I'm not sure I can use contains, I specifically want it to match the first item before a space delimited string. Otherwise, is there a way to prevent the string from matching the last word(i.e. US matches with 'ibm us')

Comment: All string methods in pandas start with `.str`. What you want is: `df.loc[df['Ticker'].str.split(" ").str[0] == 'ibm']`

Comment: @Lostsoul then you can modify your `apply` function as `data[data["Ticker"].apply(lambda x : x.split()[0] == "ibm")]`

Comment: Note, be default `.split()` defaults to space-seoerator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you are looking for `str.contains`?:

```
new_df = df[df['Ticket'].str.contains(r'ibm',case=False)]
```

which will create a new dataframe from rows that the 'Ticker' column contains 'ibm'.

You can use `or` and `case=False` (case insensitive) in `str.contains`:

```
new_df = df[df['Ticket'].str.contains(r'ibm|msft|google|..',case=False)]
```

Comment: Thank you - what if the ticker is 'us', would it match all the American tickers that have US as the end? In this case, I'm trying to specifically match with the first character when delimited with a space

Comment: How about --> ```df[['col1', 'col2']] = df['Ticker'].str.split(" ",n=1, expand=True)```, and then filter a new dataframe using ```.loc```?